# The COMPLETED view of a task list is not working

Tags: 2013, tasks, view

The COMPLETED view shows both complete and incomplete tasks. I just want to see the completed tasks when that view is selected. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someone else [suggested](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/654341c5-0d9b-4be4-905a-46f89f00009d/the-completed-view-of-a-task-list-is-not-working?forum=sharepointgeneral) that this was a bug in Feb 2015 updates and can be worked around by changing the style of the view to anything other than the default. I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

OOTB the COMPLETED view is set to show tasks that have 100% completion percentage. This means that even if a task status says incomplete and have reach 100%, it will show up in the view. This needs to change, since it's not working for your current internal process of task management.

Edit the completed view, in the same section where you select a different view.

In the filtering section, change to filter on status, rather than %completed. Set the filter to only show completed status and
make sure that only the completed tasks are filtered as visible. Save and check the result.

Comment: I am using the COMPLETED view that comes OOTB. This is what the filter looks like for this view: [Link](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=faf6c3a)

Comment: @Aamir I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I created a new view using the [Task status filter](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=b9fb2a9) but the list still displays [all the tasks complete and incomplete](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=fb818aa). Thank you.

Comment: @Aamir if you're not in a production environment, do a IISRESET, and check again.

Comment: I am sorry but I see no change after IISRESET.

Comment: @aamir that's really strange. What if you create a new task list from all site content?

Comment: Benny, the screen-shots I have been posting on this page are from a brand new task list I had created as an example for this page. We have an in-production task list that has the similar issues. Thank you.

Comment: @aamir Its a very odd behavior- and I guess I can't advice you further. Sorry

Comment: @aamir One more thing you can try... What happens if you group by status on the default view?

Comment: It does show a completed group only and no group for other status. This solution may work for us. Not exactly what I needed as we will have to expand the only group everytime we have to see the completed tasks, but will do for now. Please update your answer at the top and I will mark it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @aamir You can chose to have the default view in expanded mode!

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you Benny! Also someone else [suggested](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/654341c5-0d9b-4be4-905a-46f89f00009d/the-completed-view-of-a-task-list-is-not-working?forum=sharepointgeneral) that this was a bug in Feb 2015 updates and can we worked around by changing the style of the view to anything other than the default. I hope this helps someone.